# Cant Add value Into Array In OnSuccess()

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm really new at android development, and trying to make app with firebase. I made signup with profile photo and pushed photo name into Database. And file to FireStore. At the bottom Code `mImageUrls.add(uri.toString());` line doesn't work. But it makes toast in OnSuccess(), just I can't add data into array. I initialized Array in OnCreateView(`final ArrayList<String> mImageUrls = new ArrayList<>();`) like other arrays too. I need your help.

```
  lv = (ListView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.lv_main);


        final ArrayAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), name_list,date,imgs);

        myref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("MusiciansNonSensitive");
        final ArrayList<String> mImageUrls = new ArrayList<>();
        final StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        myref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String name_value = postSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                    String province_value = postSnapshot.child("province").getValue().toString();

                    final String url_path = postSnapshot.child("photourl").getValue().toString();
                    StorageReference photo_url = storageReference.child("uploads/"+url_path);
                    photo_url.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            mImageUrls.add(uri.toString()); // I tried to add Log.d and it adds value every for loop, but after loop it being empty array again.
                        }
                    });

                    //mImageUrls.add("A");
                    name_list.add(name_value);
                    date.add(province_value);

                }
                Log.d("LOGGOGOGOOG",mImageUrls.toString()); // Here being empty 

                //Toast.makeText(getContext(),list.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks for the trick. I just added codes here.

Answer (score 1):

`addOnSuccessListener` is asynchronous and returns immediately. The callback is invoked some time later, even after the loop completes and your call to `setAdapter`.  You're going to have to rewrite the code to only set the adapter after all the URLs have been fetched asynchronously.  You can wait for a bunch of tasks to complete by using `Tasks.whenAll()` to get a new Task that will complete after the list of tasks you provide are fully complete.